# How to access the services section of a Facebook page using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When you create a Facebook business page for a local company (eg. hair salon) you can define the list of your services (eg. Haircut, Styling, etc.) with a description and price and present them to your customers in the Services section. I'd like to export the list of services from a given page. I searched the graph api reference but it's not mentioned there.

Is there a way to access a Facebook pages services section using the graph api?

Comment: no, there is no api for that